# How to create an Issue from GitHub review comment?

Tags: github

I'm in a PR and I want to create a follow up Issue from one of a review comment. Basically, I'm sort of looking for right click on the comment and getting a 'Create Issue' option.

Please help me if there's any way to achieve this on GitHub.

Comment: I would appreciate to be able to create a *task* from a review comment, similarly to Atlassian Stash.

Comment: You can now (Sept 2018) create a new issue from a comment: see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52487407/6309).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to create a follow up Issue from one of a review comment.

2 years later (Sept. 2018), that is possible.
See "[Open a new issue from a comment](https://blog.github.com/changelog/2018-09-13-open-a-new-issue-from-a-comment/)":

> Sometimes a conversation in an issue or a pull request can move off in a tangential direction.
>   **Now you can click Open new issue within the comment’s options menu to open a new issue**, which will include a reference to the original comment – helping you get the conversation back on track.

[image: new issue]

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no such option right now, but you can ask GitHub support about it. Nevertheless, you can reference concrete PR in a new issue by typing #ID, where ID is ID of the PR. Then, an issue will be linked to PR. I think you can also mark a line in code on GitHub and link it in new issue as well.